# Monotouch - ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib giving an error

Tags: zip, xamarin.ios

Hy guys,

I'm trying to generate a Zip File with ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib library but it's throwing a really weird error.

Code:

```
public static void ZipFiles(string inputFolderPath, string outputPathAndFile, string password)       
{
        ArrayList ar = GenerateFileList(inputFolderPath); // generate file list
        int TrimLength = (Directory.GetParent(inputFolderPath)).ToString().Length;

        TrimLength += 1; //remove '\'
        FileStream ostream;
        byte[] obuffer;

        ZipOutputStream oZipStream = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(outputPathAndFile)); // create zip stream
        if (password != null && password != String.Empty)
            oZipStream.Password = password;
        oZipStream.SetLevel(9); // maximum compression
        ZipEntry oZipEntry;
        foreach (string Fil in ar) // for each file, generate a zipentry
        {
            oZipEntry = new ZipEntry(Fil.Remove(0, TrimLength));
            oZipStream.PutNextEntry(oZipEntry);

            if (!Fil.EndsWith(@"/")) // if a file ends with '/' its a directory
            {
                ostream = File.OpenRead(Fil);
                obuffer = new byte[ostream.Length];
                ostream.Read(obuffer, 0, obuffer.Length);
                oZipStream.Write(obuffer, 0, obuffer.Length);
            }
        }
        oZipStream.Finish();
        oZipStream.Close();
}


private static ArrayList GenerateFileList(string Dir)
{
        ArrayList fils = new ArrayList();
        bool Empty = true;
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(Dir,"*.xml")) // add each file in directory
        {
            fils.Add(file);
            Empty = false;
        }

        if (Empty)
        {
            if (Directory.GetDirectories(Dir).Length == 0)
                // if directory is completely empty, add it
            {
                fils.Add(Dir + @"/");
            }
        }

        foreach (string dirs in Directory.GetDirectories(Dir)) // recursive
        {
            foreach (object obj in GenerateFileList(dirs))
            {
                fils.Add(obj);
            }
        }
        return fils; // return file list
}
```

Error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: CodePage 437 not supported
  at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding (Int32 codepage) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipConstants.ConvertToArray (System.String str) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipConstants.ConvertToArray (Int32 flags, System.String str) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipOutputStream.PutNextEntry (ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry entry) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at WpfPrototype1.MainInvoicesView.ZipFiles (System.String inputFolderPath, System.String outputPathAndFile, System.String password) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at WpfPrototype1.MainInvoicesView.<ViewDidLoad>m__6 (System.Object , System.EventArgs ) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIControlEventProxy.Activated () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at WpfPrototype1.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

How can I make this code support CodePage 437?

Regards,
Claudio

Comment: According to [this bug report][1] this was fixed years ago. What version of mono are you working with?


  [1]: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mono/+bug/235858

Comment: I updated it last week. I don't think it's an update problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

MonoTouch removes I18N codepages that it cannot statically determine that you need.  You can force monotouch to keep the needed codepage collection (West) in this case one of two ways:

1. Click Project->[ProjectName] Options
2. Select iPhone Build
3. You have two options at this point
   a. Select "west" from the I18n assemblies list
   b. Add "-i18n=west" to "Extra Arguments"

NOTE: You will need to perform step #3 for every combination of configurations and platforms.

Comment: Yeah, it works. But just a question: if I'm working with zip files, it's gonna use something like Huffman's coding, reading the file/data bit per bit. So it wasn't supposed to ask about codepage, right?

Comment: I have no idea how SharpZipLib is implemented, so I couldn't comment why they need/want this codepage.

Comment: Thanks for this tip!  I had a similar problem, but with a different codepage.  Here is the list of codepages and their corresponding internationalization options: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/internationalization

Comment: This also affects MonoDroid.  In addition to the fix above, another workaround is required for Android, similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858690/get-encoding-fails-when-i-build-monodroid-project-with-unshared-runtime

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old thread, but I just spent an afternoon trying to fix this with monodroid 4.6. On the previous version the trick was to manually add a reference to the I18N and I18N.WEST libraries, but now starting with version 4.6 it doesn't work anymore. :(

So I applied a fix to the ZipConstants.cs file of SharpZipLib:

From:

```
static int defaultCodePage = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage;
```

To:

```
static int defaultCodePage = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.CodePage;
```

Comment: I had the same problem, this did the trick, however it would be nice with a better, more "clean" fix than this...

Comment: Be careful with this solution! In my case it worked too but I was not able to unzip those files afterwards. It came up with strange errors like "Central directory not found.".

Comment: I wonder why authors of SharpZibLib use OEMCodePage there. Did they mean ANSICodePage?