# How to use System.IO.Packaging in MonoTouch

Tags: .net, xamarin.ios, zip, system.io.packaging

I got a problem while trying to use the `System.IO.Packaging` in MonoTouch.
I cant found this ressource. 
Can anybody tell me where to find this ressource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see I'ts not available in MonoTouch.

If you need Zip Support, [SharpZibLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) works with MonoTouch.

If you use SharpZipLib watch out for this issue: [Monotouch - ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib giving an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600923/monotouch-icsharpcode-sharpziplib-giving-an-error)

Answer (score 2):

[`System.IO.Packaging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx) is part of `WindowsBase.dll` which is not shipped with MonoTouch (5.x).

However it's types, like [`ZipPackage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage.aspx) are not fully compatible with *normal* zip files so this might not be ideal if you're looking to process .zip files. In this case you better use alternative libraries like the one mentioned by @Jamie.

If you really want some specific types `System.IO.Packaging` then you can try building the assembly from Mono source code (open source) which is available from [gihub](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/WindowsBase).

Comment: Okay Thanks;)
I've solved my problem now by using the ICSharpCode SharpZipLib.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to zip/unzip something you might also want to have a look at System.IO.Compression.GZIPStream() which is also available in MT. Use it like this:

```
string sContent;
string sDest = "zipped file with text content.zip";
using ( FileStream oIn = File.OpenRead( sDest ) )
using ( MemoryStream oOut = new MemoryStream() )
using ( GZipStream oZip = new GZipStream( oIn, CompressionMode.Decompress ) )
using ( StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader( oOut ) )
{
    oZip.CopyTo( oOut );
    oOut.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );
    sContent = oReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I tried it but i cant zip Folders and some more files. But thank you;)