# Get Encoding fails when I build Monodroid project with unshared runtime

Tags: c#, character-encoding, xamarin.android

I am trying to use the DotNetZip library in my Monodroid app.  Everything seems to work fine when I enable the Shared Runtime build option.  When I disable Shared Runtime, the line

```
static System.Text.Encoding ibm437 = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM437");
```

generates an Exception (Encoding name 'IBM437' not supported).  I've checked every box in the "Additional Supported Encodings" list, but it does not seem to help.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you file a bug at bugzilla.xamarin.com and attach a testcase? We have a sample that uses CP1252 and works: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/SanityTests/Hello.cs#L332 https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/SanityTests/SanityTests.csproj#L110

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.

First, make sure that you've added the "West" encoding in the project properties:

[Xamarin Internationalization](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/internationalization)

If that doesn't do the trick, the problem is that the needed dlls are not getting copied to the .apk's assemblies folder. This should happen automatically, but it doesn't. I filed a bug, so you can see if it's been fixed:

[Mono for Android / Xamarin Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7543)

If not, here is a workaround that worked for me (from Xamarin):

1. Manually Add References to I18N.dll and I18N.West.dll
2. Set the 'Copy Local' properties to 'true' for both dlls
3. Add the following dummy code to get the 2 dlls added to the .apk

   > var ignore = new I18N.West.CP437();
4. Make sure that 'Linking' is set to 'None'

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just tried your solution and can confirm that it works. Thanks for posting. (My workaround was replacing every IBM437 reference with UTF-8.)